# Problem understanding the forward algorithm for HMMs

Tags: mathematics, bayesian, markov-hidden-model

I found a recursive version of the [forward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm) on wikipedia, however I don't understand the notation given in the pseudocode:
[image: pseudocode from wikipedia]

What means $$x_{t-1}$$ under the summation sign? What do I need to sum?
It would be really helpful if someone could provide a calculation example.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have a sequence of observations $x_1, x_2,...,x_T$, so $x_{t-1}$ is simply
the observation just before $x_t$ (for any $t>0$).

When simulating the forward algorithm it's useful to write a table where $T$ (number of observations) is the number of columns and the number of rows is the number of possible labels. Each cell $(t,y)$ in this table will eventually contain the probability to have label $y$ at time $t$. The table is filled column by column starting from the left, i.e. initialize $t=0$ for all labels first. Then for every column the calculation depends only on the previous column (thanks to the independence assumption).

You can find a detailed explanation [in this book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/A.pdf) for example.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! In the book you referenced the alphas don't add up to 1 . As far as I understand, each cell (t, y) is actually the alpha, right?Shouldn't the (t, y) for all ys  add up to 1?

Comment: @teoML No, the columns don't have to sum to 1 because the alphas represent *joint* probabilities, their sum for all $y$ is equal to the prob of the current sequence of observation $x_1,..,x_t$. But if each value is divided by their sum for all $y$, then we obtain the conditional prob $p(y|x_1,..,x_t)$ and these probs would sum to 1.